# Django VMware appliance

Tags: python, django, vmware

Does anyone know of a Django 1.0 + postgresql + apache + mod_python VMware appliance? A "vanilla" Django 1.0 appliance where postgresql can be installed manually would also do.

Comment: Which OS would that be running on?  Not which OS are you using to host VMWare (that could be anything) but what OS will be in the VMWare appliance running Apache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure and build your appliance at [Elastic Server On-Demand](https://elasticserver.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option I've had moderate success with

[TurnKey Linux Django Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/appliances/django)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other appliances suggested, you may want to take a look at our [BitNami Django Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) VMWare Appliance.

It is completely free and we keep it up to date, often within hours of each new Django release. In particular, it includes mod_wsgi since mod_python has not been updated for a while. One other thing that you may want to checkout is the [Django Amazon Cloud Image](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack#cloudImage). Together with the Amazon Free Tier you can have your own hosted Django for free (with some limitations in terms of bandwith, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little too heavy for your requirements, but all of those items (and a whole lot more) are included in the [Python Web Developer Appliance](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/289).

Answer (score 0):

Poulsenj is right the [Elastic Server On-Demand](http://es.cohesiveft.com/) ([Django Elastic Server Site](http://es.cohesiveft.com/site/django)) is a great place to configure and download a free custom Django VMware image in minutes.

The Elastic Server platform lets you assemble custom servers by choosing components from a library of popular software stacks. Once assembled, these custom application stacks can be configured to a variety of virtualization and cloud-ready formats, downloaded and deployed in real-time.